# Making alias of network drive yields -8060 error with Mojave

Tags: macos, network-shares, nas, macos-mojave

I am trying to create a desktop shortcut (alias). I connect to the server in question. The server with IP appears in the sidebar, as it should. I then create see the network share.

Either dragging and dropping the network share to the desktop or by selecting the network share and going File > Make Alias yields (-8060). That worked fine, when the OS was Sierra prior to the update. I had a shortcut, but the shortcut disappeared for whatever reason.

I did a search for -8060 but did not see anything.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why this is happening - I do have a workaround, though...

Rather than open the Share from Network in the side bar, open it from the Go menu > Connect to Server...  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>K</kbd>

If the server is not already listed, try connecting using `smb://machine name` or if that fails, by its IP address, eg `smb://192.168.0.40`

That should pop up a dialog similar to this

[image]

Select the volume you wish to mount & hit OK.
It will open the volume in a new window, but you can't make the alias from there, so...
Open Finder prefs & make sure Connected Servers are set to show on the desktop.

You can now make an alias of the share from the icon on the desktop.

[image]

Once generated you can, of course, move/copy it anywhere.

Comment: I did use the Go > Connect to Service, which opens up a Finder window and then on the sidebar is the IP address. I will try out steps tomorrow. Thanks for the help. I hope it works.